# vb.net use lambda to insert to specific column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, lambda

I have a database that has all of the states by name, ex: Illinois, Indiana, etc.

ID  ILLINOIS  INDIANA

I would like to insert a new row and a number in only one of the columns.  I have a variable by which I would like to look up a column (variable = column name) and then insert something in that column only.

Is this possible?

Something like below...but I can't use a string to identify the column as I'd like to below....

```
Dim obj As New DataClassesDataContext
Dim statesdb As New StatesDb

statesdb.("Illinois") = "12345"   //this is where I would like to use my         dynamic variable and save the data only into that particular column/state.

obj.StatesDb.InsertOnSubmit(statesdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions.

1. Switch to the old school datasets
2. Set the property values using Reflection. see reference in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axt1ctd9(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

In your example it

```vb
'Get the type and PropertyInfo. 
Dim myType As Type = StatesDb.GetType()
Dim pinfo As PropertyInfo = myType.GetProperty("Illinois")
pinfo.SetValue(statesdb, "12345", Nothing)
```